# Local declaration of 'photo' hides instance variable

Tags: objective-c, properties, synthesize

The compiler shows me a warning as Local declaration of 'photo' hides instance variable.
I don't understand what's going on.

```
// PTKData.h

@interface PTKData : NSObject {

    UIImage *photo;
}

@property ( nonatomic, retain ) UIImage *photo;

- ( void ) doSomething: ( UIImage * )photo;

@end

// PTKData.m

@synthesize photo = _photo;

- ( void ) doSomething: ( UIImage * )photo {

    _photo = photo;
}
```

On my understanding, **@synthesize photo = _photo** renames **photo** to **_photo** when existing the same local variable name in a method.
I can't look for the problem causing the warning in my code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: because you declare  UIImage *photo; in your .h class so change it and declare any another name

Comment: As @Sudha points out, you have TWO ivar's:  `photo` (declared at the top) and `_photo`, which is automatically created when you synthesize `photo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are creating two ivar's:

One with this line at the top:

```
UIImage *photo;  // Creates an ivar called photo
```

And the second one when you synthesize `photo`:

```
@synthesize photo = _photo; // Creates an ivar called _photo
```

I'm guessing that you only want the second one, and can simply delete the entire first line. (It isn't associated with `self.photo` at all anyway, like `_photo` is.)